# Rails - can't tell create controller which item to create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many, belongs-to

I have several models:

- User
- Relationship
- Project
- Schedule
- A `user` instance can be of type `:student` or `:employer`.
- A `schedule` `belongs_to` a `project` and
- a `project` `has_one` `schedule`
- `project` `belongs_to` a `student` and a `student` `has_many` `projects`.
- A relationship belongs_to Student and relationship also belongs_to Employer.  Employer and Student both has_many relationships.

I am writing the controller to create a schedule and I can't figure out **how to tell the controller which project the schedule belongs to.**  Here is what I have so far

```
def create 
    if current_user.type == 'Employer'
        redirect_to employer_profile_path(current_user.profile_name) 
    else
        @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
        if @schedule.save(schedule_params)     
            flash[:notice] = "Successfully created schedule."
            redirect_to profile_path(current_user.profile_name)  #change to project path later
        else
            render :action => 'new', :notice => 'Invalid Schedule'
        end
    end
end

private
def schedule_params
      params.require(:schedule).permit(tasks_attributes: [:title, :content, :_destroy]) 
end
```

I am pretty sure I am defining @schedule incorrectly.  The routes for schedule are:

```
resources :schedules
```

How do I tell the controller which Project the schedule belongs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you posted the create action for the `SchedulesController` there is no need for:

```
@schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])
```

this will probably return nil, because there is no schedule (after all that is what you want to `create` here).

```
@schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)
```

if you want to assign a project to the schedule, you need to submit this information so you can access it in the `params` hash. Something like:

```
@schedule.project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried it.  It say's it can't find a project without an ID.